# Jquery Ajax problems with IE9

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

I was using the following code to call a page method using jquery and ASP.net

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url + "/" + method,
    contentType: "application/json;",
    data: jData,
    async: true,
    success: function (res) { if (succ) { succ(res); } },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        NTF.Notify(NTF.GENERIC_ERROR);
        if (err) {
            err(xhr, status, error);
        }
    }
});
```

Everything was working fine, till i introduced the following meta tag to my pages in order for the css radius to work with IE9

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Now the code runs, it enters the success function, but then the page refreshes, I have no idea what's causing it, the code works fine in Chrome, FF and IE without that meta tag.

any ideas?

Comment: Create a working test-case on http://jsfiddle.net/. Without one, it's rather difficult to help.

Comment: how can i apply meta tags there?

Comment: Hm, you can't. But what's going on inside the `succ()` function? Can you post the complete code path leading to the redirect? Also, does it work in every other browser than IE9?

Comment: it does, tried Chrome and Firefox and IE without the meta tag. and succ() does nothing, only an alert();

Answer (score 0):

Is your meta tag before you import JQuery?  This [blog post](http://www.superficial.nl/blog/2010/08/jquery-load-or-other-ajax-functions-problem-in-ie8/) seems to indicate that you can run into weird cases when you declare a meta tag after JQuery.  It specifically talks about charset, but may be related to your problem.